# How to debug when the window is always invalidated?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, graphics

I'm finding my way through a 10000-file codebase by placing breakpoints and I'm expected to change all the GDI graphics calls to OpenGL.

The application is a standard Windows menu driven application. The trouble is, that when I place a breakpoint at any of the onDraw() functions and when the breakpoint is hit, if I mimimise the Visual Studio IDE to see my application's window, I can't see what's drawn on the window because the application's window is stuck at the breakpoint and hence does not refresh to show what it has just drawn. All I get to see on my application's window is the rectangular region of the Visual Studio IDE that was there at that position before I minimised it. Invalidated window.

I just can't figure out how to do any graphics debugging if this keeps happening. How can I put breakpoints and yet get to see what my application has drawn in it's window?

Comment: This is why programmers have two monitors.

Comment: Hope I'll be able to convince my Project Manager to get me another monitor. We work in an industry where bidding plays a major role, and a new monitor will increase the project cost. I guess it would be worthwhile if I can convince him of an increase in productivity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your application window to the place where it can't be overlapped by your IDE. Second monitor is in a great help for such things.

Comment: Or make the IDE window smaller.

Answer (score 2):

Basicly there are two options:
The first is to place the windows in a way that they do not overlap.
The second is to abandon the visual studio debugging and place cin (to break at any given place until you make an input) and cerr/cout (for the debug output) command thorough your code. You obvoiusly need a console of some sort. Starting the application from cmd might help.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [remote debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).